# What does factor VIII have to do with thromboplastin formation?

Tags: hematology

I've got the following question and I'm afraid that the question doesn't match with the answer...

Factor **III** (rather than factor VIII) is known as thromboplastin or tissue factor and it makes sense that the factor III deficiency is related to thromboplastin formation. Isn't it?

What does factor **VIII** have to do with thromboplastin formation?

[image]

Comment: The question refers to factor VIII, not factor XIII.

Comment: Typo. My mistake. Thank you for the attention.

Comment: You have 3 more typos: there is an *o* in thromboplastin.

Comment: Have you done any research, for example, looked at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_VIII) for the function of Factor VIII? If so, please explain in more detail why you're still confused. Thanks.

Comment: OP is still confused because the question he/she is quoting has a wrong answer. The correct answer is C.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thank you for the attention, it was corrected. I'm a non-native English speaker and it may happen, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Regarding to research, I did a lot, and also discussed with my friends on Whats-app group, I came here as a last resort. We have a confusion about this question. I'm confused because the factor III by itself is thromboplastin and since it's absent, then we don't need to talk about absence of factor VIII which interrupt thromboplastin formation (and by the way it is by itself not so clear, because factor III takes place before factor XIII works), I hope I explained myself well.

Comment: I am so confused... Why are you referring to FIII? The question is about FVIII (deficient/defective in hemophiliacs and patients with Von Willebrand syndrome.)

Comment: Indeed I referred to it as well, but just as possibility of a typo in the original question (FVIII instead of FIII). One of my thought was that FIII by itself is the problem of thromboplastin formation because FIII is thromboplastin. But as I said I don't reject the possibility that the question is about FVIII and I just don't know why the official answer is thromboplastin formation in this case.

Comment: As far as I can see from OMIM https://omim.org/entry/134390 there are no hereditary conditions associated with FIII deficiency so I think it unlikely that it is a VIII/III typo. I agree with @GerardoFurtado, if the asterisk is indicative of the 'correct' answer then this is a mistake in the question (or actually in the answer to the question).

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. One of my classmate claims that  Thromboplastin is involved in the conversion of prothrombin to thrombin and therefore the answer is thromboplastin ("it needs factor xa to do the conversion but it needs need also factor VIIIa to aid in the conversion"). Honestly, I still don't understand.

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent Is the formation of thromboplastin a step in blood coagulation?

Comment: "Thromboplastin (TPL) is a plasma protein aiding blood coagulation through catalyzing the conversion of prothrombin to thrombin." (wiki)

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent Okay. So if the answer is C, what is the question?